# Materialize CSS icons in Side-Nav not aligning?

Tags: alignment, materialize, diagonal

I have added a side-nav version of Materialize with icons in my page.  But when I click to expand and show the side-nav, the icons are stacking diagonally.  I can't figure out why.

[image: Materialize Icons Stacked diagonally in side-nav]

Here is the code I'm using for this.

```
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav class="headerRow">
    <div id="adminMenu" class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">BASTAS</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="narrower" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="home"><i class="medium material-icons">home</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="giveAGift"><i class="medium material-icons">card_giftcard</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="dashboard"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="recipientsList"><i class="material-icons">group</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="addRecipients"><i class="material-icons">groupadd</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="importRecipients"><i class="material-icons">system_update_alt</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="sendReminder"><i class="material-icons">email</i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="settings"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="narrower">
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="home"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="giveAGift"><i class="small material-icons">card_giftcard</i>Give</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="dashboard"><i class="small material-icons">dashboard</i>Dash</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="recipientsList"><i class="small material-icons">group</i>Recipients</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="addRecipients"><i class="material-icons">groupadd</i>Add Recipients</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="importRecipients"><i class="material-icons">system_update_alt</i>Import</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="sendReminder"><i class="material-icons">email</i>Send Reminder</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="settings"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I've searched around, and not come across this issue with other posts.

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried changing `li` height. I've done this before and someone on materialize chatter helped me, I don't remember his name. I know it is old, but it could help someone else:

```
.side-nav li>a,.side-nav li>a>i.material-icons {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
}
```